# How to monitor logrotation of logfiles in mac

Tags: macos, logrotate

I wanted to trim my logfiles when they reach 5kb(I am using for testing so i took less bytes)and i want 3 backups. this way i followed

```
vim /etc/newsyslogd/wifi.conf
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/wifi.log           640  3     5    *
```

And when i test it by giving

```
newsyslog -nvv
rm -f /var/log/wifi.log.3
    rm -f /var/log/wifi.log.3.gz
    rm -f /var/log/wifi.log.3.bz2
    ln /var/log/wifi.log /var/log/wifi.log.0
    chmod 640 /var/log/entreda_macagent.log.0
    chown 4294967295:80 /var/log/wifi.log.0
Start new log...
    mktemp /var/log/wifi.log.zXXXXXX
    chown 4294967295:80 /var/log/wifi.log.zXXXXXX
    chmod 640 /var/log/wifi.log.zXXXXXX
    mv /var/log/wifi.log.zXXXXXX /var/log/wifi.log
Signal all daemon process(es)...
    kill -1 83411       # /var/run/syslog.pid
    sleep 10
```

But when i check for trimmed files in /var/log
They are not appearing. Please help me to debug and suggest me better way to do logtrotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will appear but with some delay